# How to insert records from one table to other when multirow inserted in table using trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables:
`Table 1` and `Table 2`.
What i want to do, i want copy newly inserted records from Table1 to Table2 using trigger.
I created trigger on Table1, when bulk of data inserted in table1 it will copy newly inserted records in Table2. It work for single row insertion but not for multi row insertion.
Please let me know,what is wrong in that?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_TABLE1]
ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT AS
IF @@ROWCOUNT >=1  
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table2
(CustID
,DateCreated
,DateModify)
SELECT i.CustID
,i.DateCreated
,i.DateModify
FROM Table1 as i
WHERE (i.CustID  IN (select CustID from INSERTED) and i.DateCreated  IN (select   DateCreated from INSERTED))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't get why aren't you using the `INSERTED` pseudo table directly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_TABLE1] 
ON [dbo].[Table1] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2(CustID,DateCreated,DateModify)
    SELECT CustID, DateCreated, DateModify
    FROM INSERTED
END
```

Comment: I tried, it work for only single row insertion. My question is how to handle multi row insertion with that trigger ?it's not working for multi row.

Comment: @user2634551 The query above should work with muliple rows, there shouldn't be any issue. Did you try my answer?

Comment: :Ok i will try, might be having another issue.